# How to remove (transform - translate) of an element on click?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  background: #fc4;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS: (i want to remove the circle animation on click anywhere on the document)

```
let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

function comeWithMe(e) {
  let xPosition = e.clientX - 40;
  let yPosition = e.clientY - 180;

  circle.style.transform = `translateX(${xPosition}px) translateY(${yPosition}px)`;
}


window.onmousemove = comeWithMe;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you! Can you explain me what you're trying to do and what is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1):

This will move it back to the origin. I *think* that's what you wanted.

```js
let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
let move = true;

function comeWithMe(e) {
  let xPosition = move ? e.clientX - 10 : 0;
  let yPosition = move ? e.clientY - 10 : 0;

  circle.style.transform = `translateX(${xPosition}px) translateY(${yPosition}px)`;
}

window.onmousemove = comeWithMe;
window.onclick = function(e) {
  move = !move;
  comeWithMe(e);
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fc4;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will end the animation if you click anywhere in the document. `onclick` i am removing the `mousemove` event.

```js
let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

function comeWithMe(e) {
  let xPosition = e.clientX - 40;
  let yPosition = e.clientY - 40;
  circle.style.transform = `translateX(${xPosition}px) translateY(${yPosition}px)`;
}
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", comeWithMe);
});
window.addEventListener("mousemove", comeWithMe);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fc4;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setAttribute` or `removeAttribute`

[removeAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp)

[setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

```js
document.getElementById('para').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('para').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
});

document.getElementById('para2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('para2').removeAttribute('style', 'color');
});
```

```html
<p id='para'>clickme</p>
<p id='para2' style='color:red'>clickme too</p>
```